# why value is inserted on the database incremented by 2

Tags: mysql, jsp

here , i created a table in mysql database as follow :

```
  create table idmaker(idi varchar(20));
```

first i inserted the value 1000000001 as follow :

```
  insert into idmaker values ('1000000001');
```

then i written a JSP code as follow :

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%  
    try {  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
        Connection con=null;  
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb","root","");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select idi from idmaker;");
        String id1="";
        while(rs.next()) {
            id1=rs.getString(1);
        }

        long id2=0;
        id2 = Integer.parseInt(id1);            
        id2=id2+1;          
        Long longInstance = new Long(id2);      
        String numberAsString = longInstance.toString();
        out.write("<br>"+numberAsString);
        String query = "TRUNCATE idmaker";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into idmaker values('"+numberAsString+"');");

        con.close();  
    } catch(Exception e) { }
%>
```

when i run all above code then database value saved by 1000000003 value , while i am expecting 1000000002 value to save into database .
why 1000000002 value is not saved into database ?

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: i tried number of time and i want save the value incremented by 1 , but the  value is saved incremented by 2 ?

Comment: I did not see anything wrong. What is result of 'out.write("<br>"+numberAsString);'?

Comment: until that line the result of  'out.write("<br>"+numberAsString);' -->1000000002

Comment: but when the value is passed to database that is converted into 1000000003, why that is happening,  that is my question ?

Comment: Keep me informed if you find the reason. This is suspicious.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Because this is surely the daftest thing on the internet this morning

Comment: one simple think , i want to save value of numberAsString variable which is  1000000002 but when that is passed to database the value is incremented by 1 then saved as 1000000003, why 1000000002 were not saved ??